# Android incorrect behavior of child CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a custom `ExpendableListViewAdapter`. Like this:

- Group

  - Child
  - Child
  - Child
- Group

All his groups and childs have checkboxes.

I want parent `CheckBox` to dynamically check itself when all his children are checked.

How to implement this?

I've implemented selection of children then the parent element selected.

This is my method for it:

```
    void selectGroup(boolean isSelected) {
    for (Item itemChild : item.getItems()) {
        if (isSelected) itemChild.isSelected = true;
        else itemChild.isSelected = false;
        itemChild.setSelected(isSelected);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And I summon it inside `getGroupView`:

```
    holder.cbChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            item.isSelected = isChecked;
            item.setSelected(isChecked);
            if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) != 0) {
                selectGroup(item.isSelected);
            }
        }
    });
```

And it works fine.

I've tried to implement parent selection as well.

Method:

```
public boolean isAllChildrenSelected(int groupPosition) {
    int selectedNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildrenCount(groupPosition); i++) {
        Item itemChild = getChild(groupPosition, i);
        if (itemChild.isSelected) {
            selectedNumber++;
        }
    }

    if (selectedNumber == getChildrenCount(groupPosition)) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

And I summon this method inside my `getGroupView` as well:

```
if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) != 0) {
        if (isAllChildrenSelected(groupPosition)) {
            holder.cbChild.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

And then, in `getChildView` inside `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for child `CheckBox` I summon `notifyDataSetChanged();`.

But I'm getting some strange behavior - for example, if group have 3 childs and I'm trying to select the 1st one, it selects the 2nd and the 3rd.

I think, this is because I putted `notifyDataSetChanged();` in a wrong place, but I cannot figure out where exactly and how to fix it.

Comment: item.isSelected = isChecked;
 item.setSelected(isChecked);

Isn't this redundant?  If it's the same (updating the same field) the first method selectGroup(), you should have a llok into it, because without the {} on the if conditions it might get you a strange / unintended behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I've figured it out.

Add this method:

```
    private void selectGroupIfAllChildrenSelected() {
    int numSelected = 0;

    for (Child child: group.getChildrenList()) {
        if (child.isSelected()) {
            numSelected++;
        }
        if (group.getChildrenList().size() == numSelected) {
            group.setSelected(true);
        } else if (numSelected == 0) {
            group.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And summon it inside your `getChildView` method inside `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
        holder.cbChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            child.setSelected(isChecked);
            selectGroupIfAllChildrenSelected();
        }
    });
```

Also, don't forget to set to null your `setOnCheckedChangeListener` inside `getChildView` before you set a `CheckBox` state, otherwise you will get some strange behaviour:

```
holder.cbChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); 
holder.cbChild.setChecked(child.isSelected());
```

All this will also deselect your group `CheckBox` as soon as you deselect all the children.